# Не добавляются нули в таймере?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать так что-бы в дни/часы/минуты было всегда по 2 цифры(например 12:03:18)? 0 почему-то не появляется и цифра становится одна(12:3:18), а нужно что-бы всегда 2 цифры было? Спасибо

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const newYear = new Date('Aug 22 2022 00:00:00');

  const daysVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__days .time-count__val');
  const hoursVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__hours .time-count__val');
  const minutesVal = document.querySelector('.time-count__minutes .time-count__val');

  const timeCount = () => {
let now = new Date();
let leftUntil = newYear - now;

let days = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
let hours = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
let minutes = Math.floor(leftUntil / 1000 / 60) % 60;

daysVal.innerHTML = days.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
hoursVal.innerHTML = hours.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
minutesVal.innerHTML = minutes.toString().replace(/\d/gi, (substring) => `<span>${substring}</span>`);
  };

  timeCount();
  setInterval(timeCount, 1000);
});
```

```css
.time-count__content{
  display: flex;
}

.time-count__item{
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
}

.time-count__val>*{
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer__time-count">
  <h2 class="time-count__title">До окончания акции осталось:</h2>
  <div class="time-count__content">
<div class="time-count__item time-count__days">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">дни</div>
</div>
<div class="time-count__item time-count__hours">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">часы</div>
</div>
<div class="time-count__item time-count__minutes">
  <div class="time-count__val">00</div>
  <div class="time-count__text">минуты</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wojsbLg8/

Comment: спасибо большое))